# Converting a string with number arrays in it to actual value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I am working on a coding assignment and part of it requires taking a text input from the user that would be formatted similar to this:

```js
value = "[1, 2, 3, 4]\n[9, 8, 7, 6]\n[1, 2, 3, 4]";
```

Using .split results in the value being:

```js
value = ["[1, 2, 3, 4]", "[9, 8, 7, 6]", "[1, 2, 3, 4]"];
```

How do I convert those strings in the array back into actual arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `JSON.parse` on the split string:

```js
var value = "[1, 2, 3, 4]\n[9, 8, 7, 6]\n[1, 2, 3, 4]";
value = value.split("\n");
var arrays = value.map(a => JSON.parse(a));
console.log(arrays);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `\n`s with commas, and surround the input with `[` and `]`, so that you have a JSON representing one array which contains 3 subarrays:

```js
const value = "[1, 2, 3, 4]\n[9, 8, 7, 6]\n[1, 2, 3, 4]";
const json = '[' + value.replace(/\n/g, ',') + ']';
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're one pair of square brackets away from making your `value` parsable JSON.

```
try {
    let array = JSON.parse('['+value+']');
} catch(e) {}
```

Try/catch is good in case you can't be sure the input will be in the exact format you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the code as following:

```js
value = ["[1, 2, 3, 4]", "[9, 8, 7, 6]", "[1, 2, 3, 4]"];
```

You can do something like this to get the actual arrays:

```js
value.map(e => e.slice(1, -1).split(',').map(Number))
```

That should return an array of all your arrays.